# Search for index of a list entry in R

Tags: r, list, search

Given an R list, I wish to find the index of a given list entry. For example, for entry `"36"`, I want my output to be `"2"`. Also, how could I do such queries in parallel using lapply?

```
> list

$`1`
[1] "7"  "12" "26" "29"

$`2`
[1] "11" "36"

$`3`
[1] "20" "49"

$`4`
[1] "39" "41"
```

Comment: Maybe something like `lapply(component_list, function(x) any(match(x, "36")))` gets you close.

Comment: Your example is ambiguous because "36" is the second list element and second element in the second list element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that allows for the (likely?) possibility that more than one element of the list will contain the string for which you're searching:

```
## Some example data
ll <- list(1:4, 5:6, 7:12, 1:12)
ll <- lapply(ll, as.character)

which(sapply(ll, FUN=function(X) "12" %in% X))
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks so much! R can be a bit of a headache at the beginning.

Comment: @Josh: shouldn't your example return `[1] 3 4` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- Yep, thanks. (I did a quick code edit early on but apparently neglected to change the results bit.)  Fixed it now. Also, do feel free to edit things like that yourself (at least in any of my posts)!

Comment: This works, but why do you convert it to character first? For me it worked with just `which(sapply(ll, FUN=function(X) 12 %in% X))`

Comment: @mikey The OP's question was about a list of character vectors, so it looks like I created an example to match theirs. And yeah, it'll work  much more generally.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien. Thanks, I wasn't looking that closely at the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could first turn your list into a data.frame that maps values to their corresponding index in the list:

```
ll <- list(c("7", "12", "26", "29"),
           c("11", "36"),
           c("20", "49"),
           c("39", "41"))

df <- data.frame(value = unlist(ll),
                 index = rep(seq_along(ll), lapply(ll, length)))
df
#    value index
# 1      7     1
# 2     12     1
# 3     26     1
# 4     29     1
# 5     11     2
# 6     36     2
# 7     20     3
# 8     49     3
# 9     39     4
# 10    41     4
```

Then, write a function using `match`for finding the index of the first occurrence of a given value:

```
find.idx <- function(val)df$index[match(val, df$value)]
```

You can call this function on a single value, or many at a time since `match` is vectorized:

```
find.idx("36")
# [1] 2
find.idx(c("36", "41", "99"))
# [1]  2  4 NA
```

Of course, you can also run it through `lapply`, especially if you plan to run it in parallel:

```
lapply(c("36", "41", "99"), find.idx)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
```

For running this last bit in parallel, there are many, many options. I would recommend you weigh your options by searching through http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html.