# Finding (and returning) the first element of a list that meets a (logical) test

Tags: r, list, subset

As an example, I have a large list of vectors with various lengths (and some NULL) and would like to find the first list element with two elements.  As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577727/3897439) post, I know that with a list you can use a similar approach by using `sapply()` and subsetting the first result.  As the solution in the post linked above using `match()` doesn't work in this case, I'm curious if there is a more elegant (and more computationally efficient) way to achieve this.

### A reproducible example

---

```
# some example data
x <- list(NULL, NULL, NA, rep("foo", 6), c("we want", "this one"),
           c(letters[1:10]), c("foo", "bar"), NULL)
x

# find the first element of length 2 using sapply and sub-setting to result #1
x[sapply(x, FUN=function(i) {length(i)==2})][[1]]
```

Or, as in @Josh O'Brien's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9981224/3897439),

```
# get the index of the first element of length 2
seq_along(x)[sapply(x, FUN=function(i) {length(i)==2})]
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: It looks like @Robert Krzyzanowski's solution is the most efficient by far.  I'm not sure why the `match()` solution is slow, but its actually the worst one. Go figure!  Benchmarking comparison below for a single list of 200,000 elements. Thanks guys for all the responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
Find(function(i) length(i) == 2, x) # [1] "we want"  "this one"
Position(function(i) length(i) == 2, x) # [1] 5
```

Comment: Wow... That was fast.  I guess I should have done more homework. Thanks @Robert Krzyzanowski!

Comment: Perfect... thanks for editing with the `Find()` solution since my own use is actually to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 3):

`mapply` seems to be really quick

```
> x <- rep(x, 25000)
> microbenchmark({ x[match(2, mapply(length, x))] })
# Unit: milliseconds
#       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  243.7502 275.8941 326.2993 337.9221 405.7011   100
```

also check `x[mapply(length, x) == 2][[1]]`

Here's a different way with `sapply`

```
>  x[sapply(x, length) == 2][[1]]
# [1] "we want"  "this one"
```

This next one is interesting.

```
> x[ grep("2", summary(x)[,1])[1] ]
# [[1]]
# [1] "we want"  "this one"
```

Comment: Excellent! It looks like there are a lot of good ways to do this.  This is a nice solution, but is really a less verbose version of mine.  Given that efficiency is a concern (I'm doing this for many lists that are each 10,000+ items long), it may not be as good.  I'd like to have the operation stop as soon as the first matching element is reached. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: Check out `summary(x)`, it has a `lengths` column.

Comment: interesting regarding 'summary()` having the `Lengths` column... a good nugget to tuck away in the back of your mind.  The function using that method is very slow, though at about 681,000 microseconds on the benchmark. +1 for creativity, though!

Comment: You don't need the `{}s` around the microbenchmark expression FYI.

Comment: I think the microbenchmark you did for `mapply` must have been for a much smaller list.  See the updated benchmarks below.

Comment: Wow... if that difference if from the machine specs, I need to think about a new computer!  I thought mine was decent, but...  Just to be sure, you ran it on rep(x, 25000)?

Comment: That makes more sense now... right in line with the benchmark results I got.  Note units for yours is `milliseconds` while mine is `microseconds`

Comment: That's because there's a faster answer in yours

Answer (score 3):

I ran benchmarking on each of the solutions suggested for a single list of 200,000 elements (28.8 Mb) made from `rep(x, 25000)`.  This was just the x list from my example repeated many times.  Here are the results:

```
> microbenchmark(Find(function(i) length(i) == 2, x),
                  x[sapply(x, length) == 2][[1]],
                  x[sapply(x, FUN=function(i) {length(i)==2})][[1]],
                  x[[match(2,lapply(x,length))]],
                  x[match(2, mapply(length, x))],
                  x[mapply(length, x) == 2][[1]])
Unit: microseconds
                                                        expr        min         lq      median          uq        max neval
                   Find(function(i) length(i) == 2, x)     89.104    107.531    112.8955    119.6605    466.045   100
                        x[sapply(x, length) == 2][[1]] 166539.621 185113.274 193224.0270 209923.2405 378499.180   100
x[sapply(x, FUN = function(i) {length(i) == 2 })][[1]] 279596.600 301976.512 310928.3845 322857.7610 484233.342   100
                      x[[match(2, lapply(x, length))]] 378391.882 388831.223 398639.1430 415137.0565 591727.647   100
                        x[match(2, mapply(length, x))] 207324.777 225027.221 235982.9895 249744.3525 422451.010   100
                        x[mapply(length, x) == 2][[1]] 205649.537 223045.252 236039.6710 249529.5245 411916.734   100
```

Thanks for the quick and informative responses!

Answer (score 1):

Using `match` can work.

```
match(2,lapply(x,length))
#[1] 5
x[[match(2,lapply(x,length))]]
#[1] "we want"  "this one"
```

Comment: I think like @Robert Krzyzanowski's response, this should be more efficient... I will look at more detail on how `match()` works.  Thanks, @thelatemail!